# minted fails with breaklines and obeytabs

Tags: errors, verbatim, minted, debugging

The following example with a minted enviroment fails with the error message

```
_minted-test/7587C145B52367AE51CACC4AFB0EC13D2F785CCAC2A2CC760CA216BD1781DF79.pygtex:3: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [  b]
_minted-test/7587C145B52367AE51CACC4AFB0EC13D2F785CCAC2A2CC760CA216BD1781DF79.pygtex:3: Missing } inserted. [   b]
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{obeytabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines=true]{text}
a
    b
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

It works fine after removing one of the following:

- the tab in front of the `b`
- the `breaklines=true`
- the `\setminted{obeytabs}`

Is there an explanation for this behaviour or can this be considered as a bug?

---

The .pygtex file looks like this, intention is also a tab:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
a
    b
\end{Verbatim}
```

---

- minted requires python and pygments http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/
- minted requires the -shell-escape flag
- minted docs is here: http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf

---

- If you copy/paste the code, it will contain spaces infront of `b` instead of a tab. In order to reproduce this you have to replace it again. Unfortunately, SE seems to auto-replace tabs with spaces(https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/293906). If you know how to use tabs in code blocks, please leave a comment.

Comment: This looks like a bug. I'm working on fixing some other bugs for the next `minted` release, and will see if I can also fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update from July 2016**:  `obeytabs` is compatible with `breaklines` starting with `minted` 2.3.  This release of `minted` requires the `fvextra` package, which resolves many longstanding issues related to tabs in general and `obeytabs` in particular.

---

The `obeytabs` and `breaklines` options are incompatible due to the way that `obeytabs` is implemented.  `obeytabs` is implemented so that no breaks are possible.

The next version of `minted` will give an error message when these two options are used together. I have also opened an [issue at GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/99) to track this in the future.  Additional technical details are there.

This could be fixed, but a fix from the `minted` side of things is unlikely. `minted` uses `fancyvrb` internally to do the code typesetting. `fancyvrb` is responsible for `obeytabs`. `fancyvrb` has been largely unchanged since 1998, with minor modifications in 2008. `minted` is doing things that `fancyvrb` was not designed for, and already contains a number of patches to `fancyvrb`. This patching approach is becoming unsustainable. At some point, adding additional features to `minted`, or fixing these kinds of incompatibilities, will require a major overhaul of `fancyvrb` or a new verbatim package.